# Не получается написать метроном, то быстро отстучит, а то вообще замолкает

Tags: java, android, потоки-данных

Пишу метроном под Android и он просто ужасно неточный. Задержка раз в 8-10 сек, срабатывает криво. Иногда вообще быстро отстучит, а иногда вообще замолкает.

В чем причина?

```
btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread s1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                do {
                    mus = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test);
                    mus.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 / speed);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mus.stop();

                } while (f);
            }
        });
        s1.start();
    }
});
```

UP: следующий метод так же не помогает. + не получается добиться увеличения скорости ударов. пробовал оба метода `scheduleAtFixedRate` и `scheduleWithFixedDelay`. по ощущениям не вижу между ними разницы.

```
mus = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test);

btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mus.start();
            }
        }, 0, 120, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
});
```

Comment: ошибка в коде ps напишите код на естественном языке по шагам на бумажке и пройдите по нему по вашему коду с проставленными комментами к каждому шагу

Comment: MediaPlayer.create по крайней мере вынесите чтобы не создавался каждую секунду.

Comment: @Style-7 а тогда вообще звук не запускается.

Comment: попробуйте не без засыпания треда. сделайте бесконечный цикл внутри которого будет проверка сколько времени прошло с последнего выполнения. это будет не так эффективно, но зато с меньшими паузами

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov метраном должен стучать идеально. ваш вариант может подойти для 1000 мс. а если нужна скорость игры в 240 мс?

Comment: Не очень понял, что вам мешает сделать паузу не в 1000мс а в 240? https://pastebin.com/raw/Gr1hhzun

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov да, ваш пример работает стабильнее чем мои. но по прежнему лагает и сбивается в некоторых местах. это не подходит для метранома, к сожалению =(

Comment: может быть метод mus.start() работает слишком долго?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov скорее хаотично, чем долго.

Comment: замерьте время работы. может быть его выполнение в тайминг не укладывается просто

Answer (score 0):

Спит приложение х секунд но откуда вы знаете сколько времени будет выполнятся код до Thread.sleep(n) и после, все зависит от процессора. 
Вам поможет ScheduledExecutorService.

https://habr.com/ru/post/116363/

Например:

Код который написан в нем будет выполняться через каждые 5 секунд после запуска пока не остановите его.

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.schedule(new Runnable() { ... }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: пробовал все варианты по ссылке. все ровно криво.

Comment: Можешь показать код который ты пробовал?

Comment: обновил мейн-пост.

Comment: А попробуй свой вариант (с обычным поток), только переменную speed объявить как AtomicInteger или double что там у тебя. AtomicInteger speed = new AtomicInteger(); Его методы: 
++i - i.incrementAndGet() 
i++ - i.getAndIncrement() 
--i составляет i.decrementAndGet() 
i-- - i.getAndDecrement() 
i = x - i.set(x) 
x = i является x = i.get()

Comment: не совсем понял как это реализовать. можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в записи и чтении переменной, примитивные типы не совсем подходят для работы с потоками, рекомендуется использовать volatile или atomic.
 Инициализируем:

```
private static AtomicInteger speed = new AtomicInteger(some_value);
```

Где-то в коде меняем:

```
speed.set(some_value);
```

Сам код:

```
btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread s1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                do {
                    mus = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test);
                    mus.start();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 / speed.get());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mus.stop();

                } while (f);
            }
        });
        s1.start();
    }
});
```